# Feasibility of computing nth digit of a product of 2 integers?

Tags: arithmetic, computational-complexity

I am trying to see if there is an efficient poly-time method of computing the $n^{th}$ digit of massively large integer products, where it would take even a fast computer an absurdly long time to multiply out the two integers in full.

Suppose I wish to know only what digit lies in the $10^{1000000}$ place of the product of an integer with 50,000,000 digits by another integer with 1,000,000 digits. I do not care about any other digits in the product. Can this be done in polynomial time?

Mathematically, given two integers $j$ and $k$, does there exist a general algorithm/formula to compute only the $n^{th}$ digit of $jk$ without ever computing the full product $jk$ or computing the lowest $n$ digits of $jk$? The only knowns are $j$ and $k$ and (obviously) how many digits are in each.

If so, how would such a formula or algorithm compare in complexity to just performing the full multiplication and extracting the digit from the result? How would it compare to computing only the first $n$ digits of the product and extracting the topmost digit?

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2351677/how-to-calculate-only-the-n-th-digit-of-a-given-multiplication) attempted to answer this question, but I am unable to find an explicit formula or algorithm, only the general idea behind their approach. I am looking for a straightforward method, such as $X[n] = ???$

Comment: The standard grade-school "long multiplication" method is polynomial time, i.e. if the input consists of two numbers of $n_1$ and $n_2$ digits, the algorithm computes the $n_1 n_2$ products of pairs of digits and another $n_1 n_2$ additions.  I think you want something more like linear time.

Comment: You might look at the [Schönhage–Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm).

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, sorry, I meant linear. Actually, out of curiosity, can the individual digits of the product from long multiplication be expressed in a formulaic way in terms of the digits of the two numbers being multiplied?

Comment: Please don't put corrections or changes to the question in the comments.  Instead, [edit] your question based on the feedback, and correct all mistakes.  Then, you can flag comments as no longer needed.